# Где взять Avia Framework?

Tags: php-frameworks, wordpress

Многие премиум темы для Wordpress (платные) построены с использованием Avia Framework, а также некоторые из них используют Avia Layout Builder. Где их можно найти? И можно ли использовать для построения своей собственной темы Wordpress?

Avia Framework:
[image: Avia Framework]

Avia Layout Builder:
[image: Avia Layout Builder]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файлы можно выдрать из самой темы.